# JMETER - JMeter Response time exclude response times from Failed transactions

Tags: jmeter

JMeter Response time exclude response times from Failed transactions if successful transaction takes on average 20 secs but failed ones will fail in 2 secs.

Since JMeter is including failed response times along with passed ones, then average response times is low as compared to actual successful samples response time.

Is there any config where I can exclude response times of failure samples so that I get average response time for successful samples only?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter Success using property [jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#saveservice_requirements)

> Ensure you set property jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter to keep only the transactions you want in the report if you don't want everything.

Or from GUI:`Help > Export transactions for report`

Use regex as `(.*)(-success)(.*)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'Summary Report' listener and wanted to exclude response time of failed transactions, then please check the 'Success' checkbox. Go through the below screenshot for more details.

[image]