# JMeter - Exclude response timings of failed transaction from HTML report

Tags: jmeter

By default JMeter will include the response time of failed transactions in the calculation of the HTML report.
In my case, failed transaction will return much faster than successful ones, and are thus lowering down the average response time significantly.

Is there a way to exclude the timings of failed responses from the JMeter HTML report, while still reporting the errors itself?

I tried changing the `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` parameter to only filter for success samples, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56498651/4642486), but without success

Answer (score 0):

You're looking into the wrong response as the guy doesn't really know JMeter, as per [Sample Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#sample_configuration) chapter:

```
# Indicates which graph series are filtered (regular expression)
# In the below example we filter on Search and Order samples
# Note that the end of the pattern should always include (-success|-failure)?$
# Transactions per second suffixes Transactions with "-success" or "-failure" depending
# on the result
```

so basically `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` sampler is for filtering sample results depending on their label.

If you want to see only successful transactions response times - the feature is there already since [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31/): `Response Time Percentiles Over Time (successful responses) graph`

[image]